# remove 'Starting /bin/bash.exe' on cygwin chere

Tags: bash, cygwin, mintty

Is there a away to remove

`Starting /bin/bash.exe` when right clicking Bash Prompt Here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. edit the script called /bin/xhere. Towards the bottom, you should see something like....

```
case $1 in
 /bin/sh* | /bin/bash* | /bin/pdksh* | /bin/posh* | /bin/tcsh* | /bin/zsh*  | /bin/dash* | /bin/mksh* | /bin/fish* )
    echo Starting $1;
    exec -l $1;;
 * )
    echo Do not recognise $1;;
esac
```

And what you want to do is comment out the echo line, so it looks like

```
# echo Starting $1;
```

And that should do it.

Comment: wow thanks, I forgot I even asked this sorry for this very late answer acceptance.